# From where we can set "Build"or "Do Not Build" Contract reference for a project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, build, .net-assembly

I get following warning for almost all my projects in a solution:

```
Contract reference assembly for project 'X.X.X' not found. Select 'Build' or 'DoNotBuild' for Contract Reference in project settings.
```

[Code contracts build reference assembly actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817061/code-contracts-build-reference-assembly-actions)

But I am unable to find any hint of from where we can set this option in visual studio.

Any help on this much appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on project, Properties and on the Code Contracts tab You will find this option:

[image]

Comment: I dont see "Code Contracts" tab there.. There is only Code Analysis tab as a last tab

Comment: I assuming that you have installed the latest CC. This is a common problem, looks like your installation somewhat corrupted. Try make a Visual Studio Repair install, that may get back the cc tab. Before that you can try uninstall/reinstall CC and reboot the OS, sometimes that is enough.